# Why is it not possible to define a static (public) member of a class in the main() function?

Tags: c++

Why is it not possible to define a static member of a class in the main() function in C++? Consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A
{
    public:
    int a;
    static int b;
    A()
    {
        // int A::b = 1;
    }
    void fun()
    {
        // int A::b = 1;
    }
};
int main() 
{
    A objA;
    int A::b = 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:20:14: error: qualified-id in declaration before ‘=’ token
     int A::b = 1;
              ^
```

But when I am trying to do the same outside of the main function, it is working. What is the reason for this?

Comment: It's not possible to define static member variables inside any function. It must be done in the global scope.

Comment: Yet you can assign it in any function after it's been defined

Comment: That's how the language was designed. It wouldn't make sense to define a member of a class inside a function. What one defines inside a function has *local scope*.

Comment: I you really want to *change* the value of a `static` and `public` member in `main()` (or in any other function where the class definition is visible), then define the member outside ANY function (once in the whole program)  (e.g. `static int A::b = 1` at file scope in your case) and then change its value in `main()`  (e.g. `A::b = 2` - note absence here of the `int` keyword).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Not quite! *The definition for a static data member that is not defined inline in the class definition shall appear in a namespace scope enclosing the member’s class definition.*

Comment: About 25 years ago, I had an opportunity to chat with Bjarne Stroustrup.  I had started telling him about all my pet peeves with C++.  (He'd probably had this conversation a thousand times already.)  He stopped me right away, and said (paraphrased), "If you don't like the language you're working with, write your own.  I did."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is it not possible to define a static member of a class in the main() function in C++?

C++ is a statically typed language. That is: the "shape" of all "things" (`struct`, `class`, functions, etc) must be known in-advance by the compiler (i.e. *statically*) - and due to historical reasons C++ requires all type-names and type-members to be *declared* and (excepting for member function bodies) *defined* ahead of time (that's what `.h` files are for).

If programs were able to change the "shape" of something retroactively inside of a function then that would make it impossible for the compiler to know what the "shape" of a value is elsewhere in the program (well, this is what *dynamically typed* languages like JavaScript do, and it's why writing an AOT compiler for those is very hard).

An alternative approach, whereby the compiler *does* allow function implementations to define types is known as [Hindley–Milner Type Inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner_type_system), however C++ does not support it.

I note that the *unsolvable problem* with naïve implementations of Hindley-Milner is that it's impossible for the compiler to determine if a referenced,
non-declared, member should count as a new declaration - or as an error: so given your program - if you were to fat-finger and type `int A::B = 1;` instead of `int A::b = 1` should the compiler give you an error or should it define `B` in addition to `b`? If it should give you an error *how can it know if `B` or `b` should be the correct member?*